# How to dynamically update image to jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I am trying to create a simple application which can take an image from web cam and display it in a jlabel. but I is not working. I can't understand the reason. my complete project uploaded to [here.](https://github.com/Roledenez/TestImageLabel)
I use [this](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) library to take the image, following code does it.

```
// get default webcam and open it
    Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.open();

    // get image
    BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();

    try {
        // save image to PNG file
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("test.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     webcam.close();
```

after taking the image I wrote the following code to display the image to jlabel

```
String path = "test.png";
imageLbl.setIcon(null);
imageLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(path));
imageLbl.revalidate();
imageLbl.repaint();
imageLbl.update(imageLbl.getGraphics());
```

if there is an image already then it will display to the jlabel. but most reasonlly taken image is not shown. it's hard to explain the situation, I appreciate if you can download and check my project [here](https://github.com/Roledenez/TestImageLabel).

Comment: do you get any error ?

Comment: try repaint() and revalidate() with the frame.

Comment: @AnuragSharma `setIcon` is a bound field, it should update automatically

Comment: You already have a reference to the image (`image`), why not just simply wrap it in an `ImageIcon` and apply it to the label?  `imageLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));`.  I'm also assuming that the `JLabel` has already been added to the screen

Comment: There are no errors and program properly compile 

@MadProgrammer I use this way because I want to change the path dynamically later on my project,

Comment: In StackOverflow, you have to put the entire code of your program in the question, not in a link to outside. If the program is too long, it means you need to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it - making a new, small example program that shows the same problem that we can run (read the link). So please do that.

Comment: Ensure that: 1) You are running the label update code in event dispatch thread. 2) Invalidate and repaint the container of the label. 3) The file is really saved in earlier call.

Comment: @SelaruSinbath My point is, you don't even need to save the image to disk at all

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, you are right in this small application, but I need to backup those image for later reference in my original project, anther thing is images are taken by one jframe(this frame contain live video streaming on cam) and render(save images) in anther jframe.

Comment: @SelaruSinbath Having had some sleep, I would also suggest that `imageLbl.update(imageLbl.getGraphics());` is a bad idea, you should never call `update` or any of the `paint` methods directly, also you should avoid using `getGraphics` at all, although, I would recommend `ImageIO` of `ImageIcon`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to dynamically update image to jlabel.

```
  String path = "test.png";
  imageLbl.setIcon(null);
    try {
      BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        imageLbl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        imageLbl.revalidate();
        imageLbl.repaint();
        imageLbl.update(imageLbl.getGraphics());
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```

Comment: But how is different form using ImageIcon to load the? (Yes I prefer ImageIO, but essentially, youre doing the same thing